# Inequalities and Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

Having become so accustomed to differentiation and integration being applied just like normal algebraic operators, I was somewhat suprised yesterday when I realized that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ does not imply $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$. Intuitively this makes sense, but it's somewhat surprising considering that $f(x) \geq g(x) \Rightarrow \int_a^b f(x) \geq \int_a^b g(x)$. Can anyone think of a way to demonstrate this 'symmetry breaking' with some rigor? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $a \not < b \iff a \ge b$, they're logically equivalent.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant by that is that $f'$ cannot be *identically* less than $g'$. Do you know of a notation used for this statement?

Comment: $\neg \forall x : f'(x) < g'(x)$. $\neg \forall$ is read as "not for all $x$".

Comment: $f'<g' \neg \forall x$?

Comment: @Archaick Saying $f' <\text{ anything}$ is meaningless, since $f'$ is a function, so it must take an input in order to become a number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We usually say that *inequalities can be integrated, but they cannot be differentiated*. Which is not surprising, since integration is essentially  summing, and summing preserves inequalities. Differentiation, on the other hand, is more like subtracting, that does *not* preserve inequalities.

The following toy model might be useful. Suppose that 
$$
a(1) \le b(1), \quad a(2)\le b(2).
$$
You can infer that 
$$
a(1)+a(2)\le b(1)+b(2).
$$
But you *cannot* infer that 
$$a(2)-a(1)\le b(2)-b(1).$$ 
Try with $a(1)=0, a(2)=1, b(1)=2, b(2)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, \, f(x) = x^{-1}$$
$$g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, \, g(x) = 0$$

$f > g$ but $f' < g'$.

Also, this contradicts your claim that $f > g \implies $not $\forall x : f'(x) < g'(x)$ . A counterexample that is defined over all real numbers is easy to produce: $f(x) = 1 + e^{-x}$ with the same $g$ as above.

Comment: My counter-argument would be that if you integrate, the equality will still hold.

Comment: @Archaick see my latest edit

Comment: How about for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ;$g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ; $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \neq -\infty$; $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) \neq \infty$? Do you see what I'm getting at here?

Comment: @Archaick in which case let $f(x) = 10 - \arctan(x)$. $f' < 0$ but $f > 0$. so your hypothesis isn't true

Comment: Touche', good man.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
consider the functions:
$$
f(x)=3+\sin x \qquad g(x)=\cos x
$$

What you can find about these?